# Is it possible to import old events in a new EventSourcing system

Tags: event-sourcing

I'm current trying to choose a technical solution for this problem : How to import, (why not) replay, and access a list of events (from various internal and external sources), in an adapted system?
EventSourcing seems to be a good solution for that but I can't find if it is possible to import old events.
I must say that I can receive old events anytime, but for me the important concept is not to have the states of the objects, but store the events themselves, then give it to the apps which need it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: what prevents you from creating an event 'CustomerImported'? or faking the events to lead to the required imported state? both are valid options you can choose from

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can import old events into new system.

I have had similar problem: several event storage with different event structure (mongodb, sql, sql with json text fields). At the end of researching we decided to replicate all events (with transformation to similar structure - timestamp, aggregateName, etc) to a new event storage. And now all applications works with this new es.

The only thing you must keep in mind is reactive replication of events from old storages if they are not read-only.